# typescript equivalent for python stripping of non whitespace characters

Tags: typescript, trim, strip

- I know I can use `.trim()` for removing trailing *whitespace*
- Is there any way to trim *non* whitespace characters?

```
In [1]: s = 'abc/def/ghi/'
In [2]: s.strip('/')
Out[2]: 'abc/def/ghi'
```

I mean the equivalent of Python's `strip`, which doesn't work for me:

```
Type ".help" for more information.
> const s = "/abc/def/pop/"
undefined
> s.trim('/')
'/abc/def/pop/' # <--- last '/' was not removed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the String.replace method

```
function trimDashes(str){
  return str.replace(/^\/*|\/*$/g, '');
}
```

^ - start of the string

/* matches a slash zero or more times

| - or

/* - matches a slash zero or more times

$ - end of the string

Test it out:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATjAtgEQIYGcAWAprgBS6oBc5aYA5gJQDeAUIioVCCktQHTsAHADbYIhEgHoAegB0JAKgA+c+QBIJtADSIA5DvoBuZgF9mzCAnKJqiALy7sAIwgSAJoWAb8MCTrMWwXDghQl4hOFoSVAwcAmIyVHp6IA

Comment: I tried it with + instead of * and that works too. Could you explain the differences along with what would be ideal to use here

Comment: isn't there something simpler?